# Error in `x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]`:

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a PRIM (Patient Rule Induction Method) algorithm, but getting an error message on my dataset.  It appears to be the results of NA's, but I'm not sure what the problem is.  The package documentation doesn't mention NAs in particular, or how they should be handled.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

My code below gives this error:

> `\<error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob\> Error in` x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]`: ! Can't subset columns past the end. ℹ Locations 258, 121, 36, …, 394, and 412 don't exist. ℹ There is only 1 column.`

My code that gives the error:

```r
library(prim)
dput(HPE_LIMS_Data_041322) # at end of my message 
y <- HPE_LIMS_Data_041322$ Azoles.Benzotriazole 
x <- HPE_LIMS_Data_041322[,-1] 
HPE_LIMS_Data_041322.prim <- prim.box(x=x, y=y, threshold.type=1)`
```

Package vignette code that works:

```r
library(prim)
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
x \<- Boston\[,5:6\]
y \<- Boston\[,1\]
boston.prim \<- prim.box(x=x, y=y, threshold.type=1)
```

Data: `dput(HPE_LIMS_Data_041322)`

```r
structure(list(Azoles.Benzotriazole = c(150, 260, 160, 110, 250,
1100, 310, 320, 320, 240, 240, 320, 180, 200, 220, 160, 290,
270, 310, 250, 270, 290, 260, 240, 210, 260, 260, 260, 260, 310,
280, 270, 300, 270, 280, 21, 150, 170, 340, 40, 340, 350, 340,
320, 300, 340, 530, 590, 440, 130, 130, 200, 180, 130, 130, 130,
130, 180, 130, 190, 180, 130, 170, 240, 630, 550, 620, 530, 150,
150, 160, 270, 300, 340, 300, 280, 190, 380, 300, 320, 300, 280,
410, 430, 560, 250, 250, 160, 590, 300, 1000, 1100, 110, 270,
340, 340, 350, 260, 270, 260, 270, 330, 810, 1200, 310, 350,
0\.1, 110, 290, 270, 340, 330, 280, 340, 240, 340, 56, 290, 240,
63, 12, 120, 440, 350, 340, 270, 260, 290, 300, 260, 290, 220,
36, 280, 300, 290, 480, 220, 220, 350, 340, 350, 26, 280, 330,
360, 370, 280, 280, 270, 300, 260, 170, 260, 270, 250, 240, 270,
270, 300, 280, 320, 250, 340, 260, 380, 170, 270, 180, 120, 400,
210, 270, 210, 370, 280, 330, 120, 210, 160, 150, 160, 290, 200,
370, 270, 74, 120, 270, 44, 280, 260, 740, 280, 130, 280, 370,
370, 180, 1200, 120, 180, 1100, 790, 360, 320, 350, 330, 270,
72, 280, 390, 310, 400, 250, 250, 66, 240, 210, 210, 220, 240,
240, 1200, 1200, 290, 210, 220, 310, 240, 200, 290, 300, 350,
250, 170, 170, 250, 150, 200, 200, 150, 210, 900, 950, 430, 340,
310, 300, 430, 440, 440, 360, 350, 350, 310, 290, 7.9, 73, 260,
250, 270, 260, 760, 230, 190, 250, 250, 31, 300, 280, 190, 280,
370, 370, 210, 440, 850, 920, 740, 810, 380, 1100, 360, 900,
1100, 1200, 280, 1300, 300, 240, 310, 290, 1000, 290, 880, 300,
290, 270, 180, 880, 1500, 710, 620, 300, 240, 290, 620, 530,
530, 620, 370, 1300, 800, 810, 1400, 0.1, 300, 290, 290, 150,
360, 220, 220, 180, 320, 190, 290, 250, 1, 250, 260, 360, 220,
320, 270, 210, 200, 190, 200, 320, 330, 330, 360, 330, 180, 970,
330, 330, 490, 310, 280, 300, 270, 330, 290, 280, 190, 240, 190,
190, 1200, 280, 280, 260, 240, 1200, 250, 28, 290, 15, 340, 260,
380, 350, 310, 310, 320, 24, 260, 310, 95, 150, 210, 240, 320,
340, 350, 330, 310, 300, 260, 270, 1200, 340, 210, 1100, 7.9,
250, 280, 270, 200, 310, 300, 300, 240, 21, 440, 320, 910, 260,
1400, 220, 810, 240, 820, 250, 190, 220, 170, 240, 90, 160, 250,
220, 230, 0.1, 260, 340, 210, 210, 1400, 1500, 170, 260, 170,
190, 210, 180, 240, 160, 130, 200, 210, 250, 250, 220, 230, 230,
260, 180), Conduct.25C = c(2300, 1100, 4000, 2400, 4500, 8800,
1500, 1600, 1700, 1500, 3200, 1600, 4300, 2000, 1200, 3900, 3000,
3000, 1700, 1500, 3500, 1500, 1400, 1500, 1100, 4700, 1400, 1500,
1400, 1400, 2500, 1800, 2600, 4500, 1400, 840, 1700, 3400, 1400,
1700, 1500, 1600, 3500, 2700, 2600, 1600, 3800, 3300, 5000, 4400,
4500, 4100, 4600, 4500, 4500, 4400, 4500, 4600, 4400, 4600, 4600,
4400, 4800, 1600, 3900, 3600, 3700, 4000, 2000, 2100, 2100, 1600,
1800, 1600, 1500, 1700, 2700, 3500, 1700, 1700, 1800, 3100, 2100,
1700, 5000, 1600, 1600, 2900, 3300, 1400, 6000, 6100, 2500, 1400,
1600, 1500, 1600, 3200, 3200, 2100, 3100, 2200, 5500, 7000, 1700,
1600, 3800, 7000, 2600, 2400, 6400, 2400, 3600, 1500, 1500, 1600,
1600, 1400, 2000, 2400, 600, 1700, 5000, 1600, 1600, 4200, 4300,
3000, 4500, 4100, 3000, 4100, 1400, 5200, 4900, 1600, 4100, 1700,
1700, 1400, 1500, 1500, 1200, 5600, 7400, 3600, 8600, 2100, 3900,
3900, 1500, 2000, 3500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2100, 1600, 1900, 2000,
2000, 2100, 2000, 2300, 2100, 9000, 3800, 3200, 3500, 3700, 9600,
6600, 6300, 5500, 1600, 1400, 2500, 3600, 3800, 3100, 3600, 3300,
3700, 5600, 8900, 6600, 3300, 3000, 6100, 1900, 4300, 4100, 6600,
4100, 3300, 8600, 5400, 5400, 5700, 8000, 2300, 1800, 7100, 4700,
5500, 6500, 8400, 9600, 2300, 2400, 3500, 4800, 4400, 4800, 4100,
4200, 2500, 4100, 4300, 3100, 5300, 4000, 4000, 6900, 6900, 1500,
4200, 4200, 3000, 3100, 3200, 5500, 7200, 6300, 3200, 4800, 5300,
2900, 5000, 3200, 3200, 1900, 4300, 5400, 5900, 2200, 2500, 3100,
3800, 2500, 1800, 1800, 2100, 2300, 1600, 1800, 2500, 580, 3000,
1500, 3000, 3100, 1800, 6300, 3100, 3200, 3200, 3100, 1400, 1900,
2700, 3100, 3100, 1600, 1600, 3000, 1800, 5600, 5700, 5000, 5100,
1700, 6500, 1700, 5900, 6700, 6600, 3600, 9900, 3100, 4100, 2500,
6800, 6800, 6600, 7400, 6300, 6600, 4500, 4900, 6100, 9300, 5300,
6200, 6300, 2000, 6800, 3700, 4000, 3600, 4000, 1600, 8400, 4700,
5300, 9900, 5400, 5300, 5800, 5400, 3000, 8000, 7100, 4400, 2900,
6300, 2700, 5100, 2700, 9900, 2800, 2200, 8200, 2200, 9000, 2400,
4900, 5700, 6000, 5400, 1600, 1600, 1600, 1700, 1600, 2400, 7600,
1600, 1600, 3700, 1600, 3500, 4400, 2600, 4600, 3500, 5500, 4300,
2600, 4300, 4300, 6900, 3800, 1500, 2100, 2700, 7000, 2500, 1500,
7300, 900, 6400, 1300, 2100, 8100, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1300, 3100,
1600, 2100, 3300, 3300, 1900, 6400, 1500, 8200, 1600, 9000, 5300,
6100, 5000, 10000, 1700, 8400, 8100, 8000, 2200, 2000, 1700,
2700, 6800, 7000, 7300, 7700, 1400, 2300, 1800, 6500, 1300, 11000,
5100, 6000, 5200, 5700, 3200, 3300, 3300, 4400, 2700, 2100, 3400,
7100, 4100, 2800, 9400, 5200, 1700, 3000, 3200, 8800, 9100, 3200,
3200, 3300, 4200, 3200, 3300, 4500, 3100, 3200, 4100, 4100, 6800,
7100, 4100, 4300, 2900, 3700, 4400), Filter.Boron = c(71, 20,
NA, 72, NA, 310, 40, 47, 51, 38, NA, 42, NA, 60, 28, NA, NA,
97, 46, 37, NA, 39, 37, 36, 24, 160, 38, 38, 37, 36, 80, 49,
80, 160, 34, 22, 45, 100, 37, 52, 39, 38, 100, 73, 73, 37, 120,
100, 140, 130, 140, 130, NA, 140, 140, 130, 150, 150, 130, NA,
140, 130, NA, 40, 120, 110, 100, 110, 45, 46, 55, 41, 52, 44,
41, 46, NA, 74, NA, 53, 52, 84, 55, 50, 150, 42, 36, 76, 97,
38, 200, 200, 74, 45, NA, 41, 43, 88, 96, 61, 91, 65, 190, 230,
45, 38, 120, 220, 72, 69, 200, NA, 100, 40, 36, 44, 31, 35, 56,
NA, 18, 39, 130, 43, 43, NA, NA, 93, NA, NA, 97, NA, 34, 160,
150, 45, 110, 41, 44, NA, NA, NA, NA, 230, 240, 110, 340, 54,
NA, NA, 39, 56, NA, 55, 57, 58, 59, 36, 54, 59, 51, 60, 58, 70,
64, 310, 110, NA, 110, 120, 330, 210, NA, 170, 45, 36, 68, 120,
100, 91, NA, 93, NA, 180, 310, NA, 93, 84, NA, 57, 130, NA, 220,
140, 100, 300, 170, 170, 180, 290, 57, 39, 250, 160, NA, NA,
280, 300, 67, 60, 100, 160, NA, NA, 120, 120, 64, 120, NA, 82,
180, 110, NA, 230, 230, 37, 110, NA, 85, 80, 82, 190, 250, 220,
82, 150, 160, 74, 160, 83, 82, 40, 120, 180, 190, 61, 71, 96,
95, 74, 49, 47, 56, 62, 48, 44, 67, 15, 89, 42, 78, 80, 44, 190,
81, 84, 83, 83, 32, 45, 69, 84, 85, 48, 48, 84, 54, 190, 180,
150, 160, NA, 220, 43, 190, 230, 240, 110, 320, 85, 120, NA,
220, 240, 210, 250, 200, 210, 140, 180, 190, 330, 160, 180, 200,
61, 210, 120, 130, 120, 130, 49, 300, 150, 170, 350, 190, 190,
200, 200, NA, 300, 230, 150, NA, NA, 82, 170, 74, 320, 74, 59,
280, 56, 280, 69, 160, 190, 200, 170, 40, 40, 41, 42, 45, 69,
210, 43, 42, 110, 42, 100, NA, 70, 140, 110, 200, NA, 69, NA,
NA, 230, NA, 38, 56, 69, 240, 65, 41, 250, 26, 210, 34, 61, 310,
38, 40, 39, 39, NA, 37, 38, 78, 78, 46, 190, 25, 280, 26, 290,
160, NA, 160, 320, 44, 250, 260, NA, 55, 44, 39, 70, NA, 240,
240, 220, 20, 58, 49, 200, 26, 380, 160, 170, 150, 160, 81, 84,
84, 120, 72, 34, 80, 220, 110, 75, NA, 150, 47, 72, 82, 320,
320, 83, 83, 82, 110, 82, 83, 130, 86, 81, NA, NA, 210, 230,
NA, 130, 80, 100, 120), `Filter.Mg(CaCO3)` = c(77, 66, NA, 120,
100, 88, 21, 34, 34, 47, 61, 28, 120, 59, 30, 87, 6.2, 14, 38,
41, 19, 25, 29, 45, 60, 50, 34, 42, 30, 9.5, 16, 41, 120, 88,
52, 3.5, 55, 54, 12, 120, 26, 13, 31, 69, 46, 14, 86, 28, 200,
5\.3, 20, 97, 21, 15, 16, 4.8, 16, 20, 5, 17, 19, 5.6, 64, 19,
110, 96, 49, 120, 110, 92, 74, 17, 29, 14, 15, 4.8, NA, 140,
NA, 20, 30, 17, 20, 29, 170, 1.9, 2.7, 140, 29, 17, 55, 59, 160,
16, 15, 13, 11, 110, 80, 27, 100, 37, 92, 52, 68, 13, 87, 59,
180, 43, 96, NA, 55, 14, 21, 17, 340, 14, 53, 89, 10, 120, 210,
17, 19, 99, 68, 40, 57, 110, 41, 100, 6.5, 81, 57, 36, 160, 68,
58, NA, NA, NA, NA, 86, 120, 27, 130, 25, 69, 120, 13, 49, 58,
35, 42, 57, 52, 72, 39, 31, 55, 28, 48, 21, 27, 140, 21, 67,
100, 35, 130, 42, 19, 78, 13, 16, 86, 15, 100, 97, 63, 99, 120,
64, 130, 45, 140, 120, 32, 50, 64, 120, 32, 110, 160, 86, 43,
46, 21, 100, 83, 190, 28, 34, 38, 84, 120, 120, 48, 120, 58,
43, 64, 28, 220, 210, 150, 240, 12, 100, 72, 200, 26, 89, 90,
19, 72, 31, 39, 140, 170, 95, 140, 130, 90, 110, 59, 70, 87,
99, 98, 96, 82, 49, 73, 45, 110, 28, 250, 100, 18, 18, 87, 70,
30, 99, 200, 9.5, 160, 3.2, 130, 90, 75, 120, 100, 150, 120,
86, 9.4, 110, 230, 57, 110, 14, 21, 160, 36, 62, 25, 64, 30,
NA, 74, 10, 69, 76, 53, 43, 57, 22, 66, NA, 26, 79, 11, 8, 16,
11, 120, 40, 76, 79, 94, 66, 17, 38, 25, 49, 130, 100, 110, 11,
41, 46, 94, 61, 42, 52, 29, 72, 66, 140, 13, 69, 83, 99, 220,
39, 2.4, 72, 3.8, 2, 140, 76, 88, 43, 69, 64, 66, 91, 14, 12,
12, 9.9, 16, 140, 76, 11, 13, 29, 18, 49, 61, 230, 140, 50, 86,
60, 2.3, 43, 41, 87, 99, 23, 2, 3.7, 88, 4.4, 13, 110, 28, 85,
8\.1, 15, 120, 12, 11, 11, 24, 19, 12, 6.2, 110, 130, 25, 93,
130, 120, 140, 100, 50, 53, 90, 17, 10, 10, 71, 36, 2.8, 28,
12, 17, 9.4, 8.5, 21, 9.1, 8.7, 20, 34, 62, 40, 14, 68, 68, 53,
43, 110, 130, 110, 88, 3.2, 52, 160, 7.6, 77, 5.6, 30, 84, 11,
110, 170, 61, 98, 150, 120, 130, 75, 140, 100, 100, 150, 160,
42, 36, 8.2, 10, 64, 120, 160, 33, 67), Filter.Mg = c(19, 16,
NA, 30, 24, 21, 5.2, 8.2, 8.2, 11, 15, 6.9, 28, 14, 7.4, 21,
1\.5, 3.4, 9.1, 10, 4.7, 6.1, 7.1, 11, 15, 12, 8.3, 10, 7.3, 2.3,
3\.8, 9.8, 30, 21, 13, 0.85, 13, 13, 2.9, 28, 6.4, 3.2, 7.5, 17,
11, 3.3, 21, 6.9, 48, 1.3, 4.9, 24, 5.1, 3.7, 4, 1.2, 3.9, 4.9,
1\.2, 4.1, 4.5, 1.4, 16, 4.6, 26, 23, 12, 29, 26, 22, 18, 4.2,
7, 3.4, 3.6, 1.2, NA, 34, NA, 4.8, 7.3, 4.1, 4.8, 7, 42, 0.46,
0\.65, 33, 7, 4.2, 13, 14, 39, 3.8, 3.5, 3.2, 2.6, 27, 20, 6.6,
25, 8.9, 22, 13, 17, 3.2, 21, 14, 43, 10, 23, NA, 13, 3.5, 5.2,
4, 82, 3.5, 13, 22, 2.5, 29, 50, 4.2, 4.7, 24, 16, 9.6, 14, 27,
9\.9, 25, 1.6, 20, 14, 8.8, 38, 16, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, 28,
6\.5, 32, 6.1, 17, 29, 3, 12, 14, 8.5, 10, 14, 13, 17, 9.6, 7.6,
13, 6.8, 12, 5.1, 6.5, 35, 5.2, 16, 24, 8.4, 31, 10, 4.6, 19,
3, 3.9, 21, 3.7, 25, 24, 15, 24, 28, 16, 32, 11, 35, 30, 7.8,
12, 16, 29, 7.8, 27, 39, 21, 11, 11, 5.1, 24, 20, 46, 6.8, 8.2,
9\.3, 20, 30, 28, 12, 30, 14, 10, 16, 6.9, 54, 52, 36, 59, 2.9,
25, 17, 49, 6.3, 22, 22, 4.6, 18, 7.5, 9.4, 33, 41, 23, 33, 31,
22, 26, 14, 17, 21, 24, 24, 23, 20, 12, 18, 11, 28, 6.8, 61,
25, 4.5, 4.4, 21, 17, 7.3, 24, 49, 2.3, 39, 0.77, 31, 22, 18,
30, 25, 36, 28, 21, 2.3, 27, 56, 14, 26, 3.3, 5.2, 38, 8.7, 15,
6, 16, 7.2, NA, 18, 2.5, 17, 18, 13, 10, 14, 5.3, 16, NA, 6.2,
19, 2.7, 1.9, 4, 2.6, 28, 9.8, 18, 19, 23, 16, 4.1, 9.3, 6, 12,
32, 24, 28, 2.7, 10, 11, 23, 15, 10, 13, 7, 18, 16, 34, 3.2,
17, 20, 24, 55, 9.5, 0.59, 17, 0.92, 0.5, 35, 19, 21, 10, 17,
16, 16, 22, 3.5, 2.8, 3, 2.4, 3.9, 34, 18, 2.8, 3.2, 7.2, 4.3,
12, 15, 56, 35, 12, 21, 14, 0.56, 10, 10, 21, 24, 5.6, 0.49,
0\.91, 21, 1.1, 3.1, 28, 6.7, 21, 2, 3.6, 30, 2.8, 2.6, 2.8, 5.9,
4\.7, 3, 1.5, 26, 31, 6.2, 23, 31, 30, 35, 25, 12, 13, 22, 4.2,
2\.5, 2.4, 17, 8.7, 0.69, 6.9, 2.9, 4.1, 2.3, 2.1, 5.1, 2.2, 2.1,
4\.9, 8.3, 15, 9.8, 3.4, 16, 16, 13, 10, 26, 31, 27, 21, 0.77,
13, 39, 1.9, 19, 1.4, 7.3, 20, 2.6, 27, 41, 15, 24, 37, 28, 32,
18, 33, 25, 24, 36, 38, 10, 8.9, 2, 2.5, 16, 28, 39, 8, 16),
Filter.Mo = c(470, 130, NA, 470, NA, 2300, 250, 320, 340,
230, NA, 260, NA, 430, 190, NA, NA, 700, 320, 230, NA, 250,
230, 230, 150, 1100, 230, 230, 240, 240, 580, 310, 270, 1100,
220, 140, 280, NA, 250, 330, 250, 240, NA, 480, 440, 240,
860, 770, 1000, 840, 840, 770, NA, 830, 830, 850, NA, 920,
840, NA, 890, 820, NA, 260, 840, 760, 770, 830, 300, 310,
350, 280, 320, 280, 220, 320, NA, 600, NA, 350, 350, NA,
400, 360, 1200, 280, 230, 460, 690, 230, 1500, 1400, 480,
290, 300, 300, NA, 490, NA, 360, 510, 430, 1400, 1600, 290,
130, 910, 1600, 460, 440, 1200, NA, 530, 250, 220, 270, 180,
240, 370, 200, 110, 240, 970, 250, 250, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, 240, 1000, 970, 310, 860, 280, 300, NA, NA, NA, NA,
1300, 1500, 530, 2100, 340, NA, NA, 260, 390, NA, 360, 390,
390, 400, 240, 370, 390, 360, 410, 390, 460, 410, 2100, 740,
NA, 710, 790, 2200, 1500, NA, 1200, 260, 230, 470, 790, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1200, 2100, NA, NA, NA, NA, 350, 870, NA,
1700, 780, 560, 1900, 1100, 1100, 1200, 2000, 380, 260, 1800,
1100, NA, NA, 1800, 2000, 430, 400, NA, 1100, NA, NA, 810,
820, 410, 800, NA, 560, 1200, 680, NA, 1800, 1800, 260, 760,
NA, NA, 540, 540, 960, 1600, 1300, 530, 960, 1100, 500, 990,
540, 570, 270, 820, 1300, 1400, 390, 440, NA, 650, 450, 330,
310, 380, 410, 350, 290, 440, 100, 580, 270, 520, 550, 290,
1500, 550, 530, 550, 560, 230, 290, 430, 520, NA, 350, 350,
NA, 380, 1300, 1300, 1100, 1200, NA, 1600, 240, 1500, 1700,
1800, NA, 2500, NA, 930, NA, 1500, 1600, 1400, 1700, 1300,
1400, 1100, 1300, 1500, 2300, 1200, 1400, 1400, 340, 1400,
950, 1000, 940, 1000, 260, 2000, 1200, 1300, 2600, 1300,
1200, 1300, 1300, NA, 1900, 1800, 860, NA, NA, NA, 1100,
450, 2400, 450, 360, 1800, 370, 1800, 440, 1100, 1300, 1400,
1200, 270, 270, 280, 260, 250, 420, 1600, 240, 220, 810,
220, NA, NA, 470, 990, 730, 1000, NA, 460, NA, NA, 1800,
NA, 240, 370, 460, 1800, 430, 290, 1600, 180, 1400, 240,
290, 1900, 250, 260, 250, 270, 490, 260, 280, NA, NA, 290,
1200, 160, 1800, 160, 1900, 1000, NA, 1100, 2600, 350, 2100,
2100, 300, 340, 270, 260, 470, NA, 1600, 1900, 1500, 140,
450, 320, 1500, 180, 2700, 970, 1400, 950, 1300, 530, 550,
550, 780, 490, 220, 530, 1500, 720, 520, 310, 950, 330, 480,
530, 2300, 2400, 540, 540, 540, 730, 530, 540, 850, 570,
530, NA, NA, 1400, 1500, NA, 790, 530, 680, 780), Filter.SiO2 = c(NA,
100, NA, NA, 160, 390, 180, 220, 240, 170, NA, 180, NA, 180,
130, NA, NA, 210, 210, 170, NA, 180, 170, 170, 120, 190,
170, 160, 170, 190, 220, 150, 200, 320, 160, 130, 180, NA,
170, NA, 170, 180, NA, 310, 280, 170, 300, 340, 160, 210,
240, 220, 220, 230, 230, 220, 260, 230, 220, NA, 230, 210,
NA, 150, 280, 260, 270, 240, 180, 130, 160, 190, 180, 190,
NA, NA, NA, 140, NA, NA, 180, 170, 230, 190, 190, 180, 130,
160, 340, 190, 760, 870, NA, NA, 210, 100, NA, 150, 190,
NA, 150, NA, 520, 1000, 170, 86, 310, 880, NA, 160, 270,
NA, 180, 180, 190, 200, 130, 180, 170, 100, 80, 160, 170,
190, 190, NA, 200, NA, NA, 230, NA, NA, 160, 170, 220, 180,
160, 160, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 210, 330, 230, 350, NA, 200,
220, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 170, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, 380, 220, NA, 310, 220, 370, 220, 210, 240, 180,
180, 250, 220, 150, NA, NA, 210, NA, 280, 340, 210, NA, NA,
200, NA, 180, 150, 210, 150, 170, 1000, 470, 540, 190, 700,
170, 190, 560, 550, NA, 190, 310, 350, 160, 170, 210, 510,
NA, NA, 400, 410, 170, 460, 190, 160, 590, 190, 180, 570,
550, 210, 210, 190, NA, 240, 190, 230, 320, 280, 190, 300,
250, 190, 230, 200, 160, 180, 220, 570, 470, 190, 180, 180,
150, 180, NA, NA, 170, 170, 200, 140, 320, 75, 390, 170,
260, 200, 100, 220, 180, 240, 240, 210, 160, 120, 150, 200,
NA, 190, 190, NA, 220, 390, 400, 330, 390, NA, 490, 170,
380, 560, 690, 170, 370, NA, 170, NA, 210, 610, 210, 200,
230, 200, 410, 170, 550, 1000, 350, 170, 230, 170, 210, 270,
270, 260, 300, 190, 520, 450, 390, 360, 530, 220, 170, 170,
NA, 330, 210, 230, 180, 190, NA, 170, 200, 380, 170, 190,
380, 160, 290, 160, 520, 300, 270, 330, 190, 190, 190, 210,
190, 140, 260, 180, 170, 320, 170, 210, NA, 190, 400, 320,
210, NA, 180, 140, 140, 670, NA, 210, 180, 160, 710, 130,
190, 300, 110, 350, 160, NA, 310, 210, 200, 210, 180, 170,
180, 330, 120, 160, 78, 280, 100, 310, 110, 290, 390, NA,
320, 400, 220, 250, 530, 47, 140, 64, 200, 76, 190, 180,
220, 230, NA, 300, 220, 680, 140, 320, 310, 400, 130, 370,
150, 130, 160, 110, 180, 300, 89, 160, 140, 160, 12, 180,
NA, 130, 200, 660, 760, 170, 180, 130, 79, 170, 110, 150,
220, 180, 140, 160, 150, 160, 150, 220, 200, 130, 100), Filter.Si = c(NA,
48, NA, NA, 73, 180, 84, 100, 110, 78, NA, 83, NA, 84, 60,
NA, NA, 97, 100, 78, NA, 82, 78, 78, 56, 88, 80, 77, 77,
91, 100, 68, 92, 150, 73, 62, 83, NA, 80, NA, 80, 83, NA,
150, 130, 80, 140, 160, 74, 100, 110, 100, 100, 110, 110,
100, 120, 110, 100, NA, 110, 100, NA, 69, 130, 120, 130,
110, 86, 61, 75, 90, 86, 89, NA, NA, NA, 66, NA, 110, 85,
79, 110, 88, 90, 82, 62, 77, 160, 91, 360, 410, NA, NA, 97,
47, NA, 71, 87, NA, 72, NA, 240, 470, 82, 40, 140, 410, NA,
74, 130, NA, 85, 86, 88, 92, 63, 85, 82, 47, 37, 77, 78,
89, 89, NA, 93, NA, NA, 110, NA, NA, 76, 79, 100, 84, 75,
76, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 150, 110, 160, NA, 91, 100,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 82, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
180, 100, NA, 140, 100, 170, 100, 98, 110, 86, 86, 120, 100,
69, NA, NA, 96, NA, 130, 160, 100, NA, NA, 93, NA, 86, 70,
97, 72, 82, 490, 220, 250, 90, 330, 81, 87, 260, 260, NA,
91, 140, 160, 76, 79, 97, 240, NA, NA, 190, 190, 79, 210,
90, 77, 280, 87, 83, 270, 260, 97, 96, 87, NA, 110, 87, 110,
150, 130, 89, 140, 120, 88, 110, 93, 74, 85, 100, 270, 220,
88, 83, 83, 70, 86, NA, NA, 77, 79, 94, 67, 150, 35, 180,
78, 120, 95, 47, 100, 82, 110, 110, 96, 74, 57, 69, 92, NA,
88, 91, NA, 100, 180, 190, 150, 180, NA, 230, 80, 180, 260,
320, 82, 170, NA, 80, NA, 100, 280, 96, 94, 110, 95, 190,
78, 260, 480, 160, 81, 110, 77, 99, 130, 130, 120, 140, 88,
240, 210, 180, 170, 250, 100, 79, 79, NA, 150, 99, 110, 83,
90, NA, 79, 93, 180, 80, 91, 180, 75, 140, 75, 240, 140,
130, 150, 87, 88, 91, 99, 89, 67, 120, 84, 81, 150, 78, 96,
NA, 90, 190, 150, 96, NA, 86, 68, 68, 320, NA, 99, 86, 75,
330, 61, 88, 140, 50, 160, 77, NA, 140, 97, 95, 98, 82, 78,
84, 150, 57, 74, 37, 130, 49, 140, 50, 140, 180, NA, 150,
190, 100, 120, 250, 22, 67, 30, 94, 35, 90, 85, 100, 110,
NA, 140, 100, 320, 65, 150, 140, 190, 60, 170, 72, 62, 73,
50, 84, 140, 42, 76, 65, 75, 5.7, 84, NA, 63, 95, 310, 350,
81, 86, 63, 37, 81, 52, 69, 100, 85, 64, 73, 71, 77, 72,
100, 92, 63, 48), pH.25C = c(8.4, 7.9, 9, 8.3, 8.8, 9.5,
9\.3, 9.2, 9.6, 8.5, 9.2, 9.1, 9.4, 8.2, 8.1, 9, 9.2, 8.9,
9\.1, 8.6, 9, 9, 8.6, 8.4, 8, 9, 8.7, 8.5, 8.6, 10.2, 9, 8.2,
9\.9, 8.9, 8.1, 10.3, 8.3, 9.2, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.9, 9.5, 9.5,
9\.6, 9.8, 9.1, 9.6, 8.8, 9.2, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2,
9\.2, 9.3, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3, 9.2, 9.4, 9.1, 9.1, 9.1, 9.3, 9.1,
8\.9, 8.3, 8.5, 9.3, 8.3, 9.7, 9.2, 9.7, 9, 8.8, 8.2, 9.3,
8\.3, 9, 9.3, 8.7, 9, 9.2, 9, 8.6, 9.7, 9.5, 10.2, 10.3, 8.3,
10, 10, 10.1, 10.1, 8.6, 8.7, 9.9, 8.6, 9.3, 9.5, 10.4, 9.7,
9\.9, 9.1, 10.4, 9.7, 8.5, 9.2, 8.4, 8.9, 9.8, 9.2, 9.8, 8.2,
9\.3, 8.5, 8.2, 9.6, 8, 8.9, 9.8, 9.8, 8.9, 8.9, 9.4, 9.2,
8\.8, 9.4, 9, 10.6, 9, 9, 8.5, 8.9, 8.4, 8.1, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8,
10\.5, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 9.4, 9.1, 8.9, 8.8, 9.8, 8.9, 9.3, 9,
9\.1, 8.9, 9, 8.5, 9, 9.2, 8.6, 9.5, 9, 9.4, 9.7, 9.5, 9,
9\.6, 9, 8.9, 9.5, 9.1, 9.2, 9.2, 9.8, 9.3, 8.6, 8.9, 9.1,
9\.1, 9.1, 9.1, 9.5, 9.2, 9.5, 9.2, 8.3, 8.5, 9.1, 10, 8.8,
8\.7, 9.2, 8.8, 8.9, 10.4, 9.8, 10.1, 9.1, 9.8, 8.5, 8.5,
9\.9, 10, 10.2, 9.2, 9.4, 9.5, 8.5, 8.6, 8.9, 9.8, 9.2, 10,
9, 8.9, 8.6, 9.2, 9, 8.9, 9.6, 9.1, 8.9, 10.1, 10, 8.8, 9,
9, 9.4, 8.9, 8.7, 9.3, 9.3, 9.2, 8.9, 9.2, 9.2, 8.8, 8.9,
8\.9, 8.8, 8.1, 9.1, 9.8, 9.5, 8.9, 8.6, 9.2, 8.2, 8.6, 9.4,
9\.4, 8.4, 8.4, 8.7, 9.5, 9.5, 9.9, 10.1, 9.1, 8.9, 8.9, 9,
9\.3, 8.8, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 10.7, 9.4, 9.3, 9, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7,
8\.9, 8.9, 9.5, 9.7, 9.4, 9.6, 10.1, 9.6, 9.9, 9.5, 9.8, 9.9,
9, 9.6, 9.1, 8.5, 9.2, 9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.3, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3,
9\.1, 9.7, 10.2, 9.4, 9.1, 9.1, 8.3, 9.2, 9.2, 9.1, 9, 9,
9\.9, 9.9, 9.8, 9.4, 9.6, 9.9, 9.1, 9.2, 9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.2,
9, 8.5, 9.3, 9, 9, 9.1, 9.7, 9, 9.1, 9.4, 8.3, 9.4, 8.5,
9\.5, 9.3, 9.1, 9.3, 9.5, 10, 9.8, 9.7, 9.7, 8.2, 9.4, 9.8,
10\.1, 9.6, 9.2, 8.9, 9.2, 9.2, 9.6, 9.6, 9.3, 9.4, 9.1, 8.9,
8\.9, 10.1, 8.8, 8.7, 9.3, 9, 10.2, 9.3, 10.9, 9.3, 9, 9.2,
10\.3, 10.3, 9.4, 9.6, 9.7, 10, 10.5, 9.1, 9.6, 10, 8.7, 8.7,
9, 9.3, 8.6, 9.5, 8.6, 9.5, 10, 9.8, 9.5, 9.7, 10.3, 9.4,
9\.8, 9.9, 9, 8.8, 9.9, 8.9, 9.2, 9.4, 9.3, 9.3, 11, 9.8,
9\.8, 10, 8.9, 9.7, 9.5, 9.4, 9, 9.4, 8.7, 8.3, 8.7, 8.7,
9\.1, 10.2, 8.5, 9.3, 8.5, 8.9, 9.9, 9.1, 10.2, 8.6, 8.7,
10, 10, 8.6, 8.9, 8.5, 8.6, 8.6, 8.7, 9, 8.9, 8.6, 8.8, 8.9,
9\.1, 9.2, 8.6, 9.2, 8.7, 8.9, 8.7)), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -451L))
```

Tried googling `"Error in 'x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]':"`.

I haven't worked with R much since school 20 years ago. The vignette code produced a 'boston.prim' object that's a list with 9 items.

############ boston.prim ############

```r
> str(boston.prim)
> List of 9
> $ x            :List of 2
> ..$ :'data.frame':    217 obs. of  2 variables:
> .. ..$ nox: num \[1:217\] 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 0.538 ...
> .. ..$ rm : num \[1:217\] 6.58 5.95 6.1 5.83 5.93 ...
> ..$ :'data.frame':    289 obs. of  2 variables:
> .. ..$ nox: num \[1:289\] 0.469 0.469 0.458 0.458 0.458 0.524 0.524 0.524 0.524 0.524 ...
> .. ..$ rm : num \[1:289\] 6.42 7.18 7 7.15 6.43 ...
> $ y            :List of 2
> ..$ : num \[1:217\] 0.00632 0.62976 0.63796 0.62739 1.05393 ...
> ..$ : num \[1:289\] 0.0273 0.0273 0.0324 0.069 0.0299 ...
> $ y.fun        :List of 2
> ..$ : num 7.62
> ..$ : num 0.604
> $ box          :List of 2
> ..$ : num \[1:2, 1:2\] 0.533 0.74 3.039 7.072
> .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
> .. .. ..$ : NULL
> .. .. ..$ : chr \[1:2\] "nox" "rm"
> ..$ : num \[1:2, 1:2\] 0.336 0.92 3.039 9.302
> .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
> .. .. ..$ : NULL
> .. .. ..$ : chr \[1:2\] "nox" "rm"
> $ mass         :List of 2
> ..$ : num 0.429
> ..$ : num 0.571
> $ num.class    : int 2
> $ num.hdr.class: int 1
> $ threshold    : num 3.61
> $ ind          : num 1

- attr(\*, "class")= chr "prim"
```

############  expecting output below ############

```r
> summary(boston.prim, print.box=TRUE)
> box-fun  box-mass threshold.type
> box1    7.6222290 0.4288538              1
> box2\*   0.6035267 0.5711462             NA
> overall 3.6135236 1.0000000             NA

Box limits for box1
nox     rm
min 0.5332 3.0391
max 0.7400 7.0718

Box limits for box2
nox     rm
min 0.3364 3.0391
```

Comment: Do you have a space in `HPE_LIMS_Data_041322$Azoles.Benzotriazole`  (i.e. `HPE_LIMS_Data_041322$ Azoles.Benzotriazole`)?

Comment: What are the values in your data with a `\\` in them? Reading your data into R doesn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't realize I timed out on my edits.  1) No space in...$Az....  I realize there looks like there might be, but I cut and pasted that variable name directly from the RStudio object.  @jared

Comment: 2) I don't know what those slanted marks are.  It seems Stack Exchange added them due to my user error.  StkExch wouldn’t let me post without indenting my code 4 spaces.  Said I could do it automatically by CTRL-K.  Tried that, got weird slanted characters, tried to fix it, made it worse.  @nrennie